# How to implement multicurruncy using context in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want functionality of multicurruncy in react native like when user select $ whole currency converted into $ in app, how to achieve this I search on google but not find a satisfied answer. Pls help, thanks in advance. I think used context api is easy way.. .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example in Typescript

*CurrencyContext.tsx*

```
type CurrencyType = 'USD' | 'EUR' | 'TND' | string;
            
type CurrencyContextType = {
  currency: CurrencyType;
  setCurrency: (value: CurrencyType) => void;
};

const default: CurrencyContextType = {
  currency: 'USD',
  setCurrency: () => {},
};

export const CurrencyContext = createContext<CurrencyContextType>(default);

export const CurrencyProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('USD');

  return (
    <CurrencyContext.Provider value={{ currency, setCurrency }}>
      {children}
    </CurrencyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCurrency = () => useContext(CurrencyContext);
```

*In your index.ts (or your root file)*

```
import { CurrencyProvider } from './CurrencyContext';

// ...

<CurrencyProvider>
  <App />
</CurrencyProvider>
```

*Example of use in your components :*

```
import { useCurrency } from './CurrencyContext';

// ...

const { currency, setCurrency } = useCurrency();
```

Use `currency` to get the currency currently in use and `setCurrency` to change the currency throughout the application